# Pip uninstall Odd Package whose name starts with -

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I was trying to install the package [`spherecluster`](https://github.com/jasonlaska/spherecluster) using `pip` in a `conda` environment. Upon successful installation, I noticed that an odd package was being listed with `pip list`, in addition to `spherecluster`:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\****> pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
-pherecluster                      0.1.7
      :                              :
```

It also causes problems when I try to `pip freeze`:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\****> pip freeze
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -pherecluster 0.1.7 (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-pherecl'": Expected W:(abcd...)
alabaster==0.7.12
:
```

Because the name starts with '-', the following happens when I try to uninstall it:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\****> pip uninstall -pherecluster

Usage:
  pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: -p
```

Wrapping the name in quotation marks didn't help. No suitable options in `pip uninstall` documentation were helpful. Any idea how to uninstall such an oddly named package?

Comment: I think it should be good enough to simply delete the `-pherecluster*` files and directories in `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`.

Comment: @phd I was more looking for a `pip uninstall` variant or so rather than a manual workaround. Does that mean there is no "automatic" solution?

Comment: There is no. Those packages are broken and are beyond reach of `pip`. They require manual fix.